# Tag display issue while editing a question

Tags: bug, tags, editing

When I edit a question with Chrome v67 tags edits display:

[image: tags justified to far left]

It happens every time for me on this question: [How do I communicate to a problem employee that they are being moved to a field office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/116355/16)

The first 3 tags are not visible while editing.

Comment: I can confirm this happens to me also with Chrome on my Linux computer, but not on Firefox (could this be a network-wide bug?) Seems to me that the question you linked has 5 tags. Have you tried with other questions, perhaps some that don't have 5 tags? Or in other sites? (I'm busy right now but will check out later)

Comment: I tried in SO and it seems that the bug is there as well...

Comment: That happens to me any time I edit a tag list where the width of the existing tags exceeds the width of the edit box (long tag names and several tags).  Definitely Chrome; I think Firefox too.  It's irritating. :-(

Comment: @MonicaCellio I tried in FF and no problem... I also tested with some posts with 5 tags but found no problem; seems that what you say, regarding the width exceeding the box, is the cause of this issue on Chrome (some sort of overflow of some sort)

Comment: I just checked and I get this behavior in Firefox.  On the linked question, I see half of one tag.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Should this be bumped to the main Meta site, or do site mods get pinged for [meta-tag:bug] tags on individual site metas as well?

Comment: @DavidK devs are supposed to monitor bugs on per-site metas, but if somebody wants to post on main meta that wouldn't be wrong.  Ideally, reproduce the problem on another site to validate the claim that it's not just us (something in our design).

Comment: I posted here because I am a dev and I found a bug I could reproduce.  As a dev I appreciate people giving me this type of info.   Feel free to post on main and risk the wrath of the Meta.SE NIMBY Folks.